# Save int variable on Cloud for android mobile application

Tags: android, service, save

I need to save a single variable (integer) on the cloud, for an Android app. Should I have to use the Google services rescue services for just one integer number?
It's very complicated?

I have used the Unity 3D and on the Google console the app is already enabled with save games.

Comment: Thanks for editing, Muazzam, 
My English is bad. I know.

Answer (score -2):

You can save int shared preference in Android.

**Saving data as:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =  getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("key, 2);
editor.commit();
```

**Get the data as:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =  getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int val = sharedpreferences.getInt("idName", -1); // -1 is the default value
```

Comment: This is neither for Unity3D and neither stored online.

Comment: This method where save the data? Would the information be shared if the user has two or more devices?

I need to save the variable online so that it is a data shared by all the user's devices.

I need to save the variable online so that it is a data shared by all the user's devices.

But looking at the tutorials, the use of the Goggole save game service seems like a big job, especially if I have to save a single integer value only.